# HTML and CSS: What do the <ul> and <li> tags stand for?

Tags: css, html

In the following lines of CSS code:

```
.sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {top: 40px!important; }
```

What do the HTML tags `<ul>` and `<li>` mean?

Comment: You'll need to learn HTML before CSS can be of any use. I'd suggest reading the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They target `<ul>` and `<li>` elements in the page.

In CSS an id is prefixed by `#`, a class is prefixed by `.`, and an element has no prefix at all.

So the selector `.sf-menu li:hover ul` will apply to any `<ul>` element, inside an `<li>` element that you are currently pointing at, inside an element with `class="sf-menu"`.

The selector `.sf-menu li.sfHover ul` will apply to any `<ul>` element, inside an `<li>` element with `class="sfHover"`, inside an element with `class="sf-menu"`.

Answer (score 31):

It's from the HTML elements of the same name.

UL - Unordered List (an ordered, or numbered, list would be OL)
LI - List Item

Answer (score 11):

`ul` stands for unordered list.

`li` stands for list item.

They are the HTML tags for "bulleted" lists as opposed to "numbered" lists (which are specified by `ol` for ordered list).